# Inconsistent Permission Error on postgres schema

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-12, asyncpg

I have remote database server and I have different roles and users. for example I have database `test` and schema `test_schema` and table `test1`.

I am connected to the database using `test_user` and I am querying the table like below.

```
select * from test_schema.test1
```

It works fine sometime and some time it fails with below error.

```
InsufficientPrivilegeError: permission denied for schema test_schema
```

Here the actual problem is inconsistency of the error, if it does not have permission why it works some time?

Additional info:

1. using python3
2. using asyncpg

Comment: I’d say best way to look into this is first get all the permissions on that schema/schemas. Then make sure your driver is not causing the problem and is the latest one. Not sure of you are using psycopg or a different one. Do share the effective permissions from the db. I’m suspecting its the driver or otherwise the async library. See how it works when you use psycopg driver.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug at their issues page - [here](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues). This error seems very strange. Are you sure your error response if for the right db user? Is your async code alright?